Converting SoilGrids data to Volumetric fractions
The SoilGrids data provides:

mass fraction of organic matter in the fine earth fraction (q_om = mass_om/mass_fine_earth)
percent of fine earth minerals in clay, silt, sand in the fine earth fraction, by mass. These sum to 1 and hence cannot be e.g. q_clay = mass_clay/mass_fine_earth.
volumetric fraction of coarse fragments in the whole soil (vol_cf/vol_soil)
bulk density of the fine earth soil, oven dry. I assume this is mass of fine earth/volume of whole soil, or (mass_om+mass_clay+mass_silt+m_sand)/vol_soil.

I would like to compute the volumetric fractions of the fine earth components relative to the whole soil, like we have for the coarse fragments. (vol_clay, vol_silt, vol_sand, vol_om/volume_soil).
I did the following:
(1) Obtain q_clay, q_silt, q_sand, as follows:

q_minerals = 1-q_om, since the only mass in the fine earth when dry is due to minerals and organic matter.
q_clay = %clay x (1-q_om), and same for silt and sand. Let's denote q_clay+q_sand+q_silt = q_minerals.
Again, these are mass fractions of a component relative to the mass of the fine earth, and we have q_om + q_minerals = 1.

(2) Obtain volumetric fractions of clay, silt, sand, om relative to whole soil:

vol_clay/vol_soil = mass_clay/mass_fine_earth x vol_clay/mass_clay x mass_fine_earth/vol_soil = q_clay/density of clay x bulk density of fine earth, where the density of clay is ~2.7g/m^3
Repeat with q_om, q_silt, q_sand. I used the same density for silt and sand and clay, and 1.3g/cm^3 for om.

(3) Sanity check that vol_cf/vol_soil (from SoilGrids directly) + vol_silt/vol_soil + vol_clay/vol_soil + vol_sand/vol_soil + vol_om/vol_soil is between 0 and 1.
The last step fails.
Where is my mistake? Or is this correct, but the data is not expected to obey this constraint since it is produced by an ML model without knowledge of the constraint?
